# keras.utils.plot_model returning TypeError

Tags: tensorflow, plot

I have the model created with the below code:

```
title = keras.Input(shape=(vocabulary_size,), name="title")
text_body = keras.Input(shape=(vocabulary_size,), name="text_body")
tags = keras.Input(shape=(num_tags,), name="tags")

features = layers.Concatenate()([title, text_body, tags])
features = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(features)

priority = layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid", name="priority")(features)
department = layers.Dense(num_departments, activation="softmax", name="department")(features)

model = keras.Model(inputs=[title, text_body, tags], outputs=[priority, department])
```

When I execute `keras.utils.plot_model(model,'classifier.png')`, I get a TypeError saying `TypeError: tuple expected at most 1 arguments, got 2`. Can you please explain why I am getting this?